# How to avoid table data splitting between two pages using jspdf

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

Is there a way to fix data splitting between two pages (I've posted the image of the issue below). I'm passing a template to doc.html() and im using jspdf to generate a pdf file. Everything is displayed as it should except the table data - the table data splits between two pages (see image below).

This is the part of the code to generate the pdf. HTMLTemplate is html template im passing to it (divs and tables with data)

```
let doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4");

doc.html(renderToString(<HTMLTemplate />), {
margin: [20, 0, 20, 0]
 async callback(doc) {
        // save the document as a PDF
        doc.save(name_pdf_file, { returnPromise: true }).then(SetValue()); // Ignore this
      },
    });
```

[image]